# Is it possible to add additional logic to the Parse Server?

Tags: parse-server

I want to perform some actions on X value depending on input from received in Y value. Can I perform such actions writing server side code in parse server? 
Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom server side code can be achieved via cloud code. Cloud code allows you to create custom functions that are written in NodeJS and those functions can do various operations like: query from database, integrate with other solutions like: social, sending emails and more. The big advantage in parse-server is that you can use any npm module that you like from within the cloud code function and because there are millions of modules out there you have unlimited options.

Another very cool features of cloud code is the **server side hooks**
server side hooks allows you to write a code that will be triggered by parse-server core when an object is being saved or deleted. such events can be:
 **beforeSave** - do something before the object is being saved to the database
**afterSave** - do something after the object is being saved
**beforeDelete** - do something before deleting

and more and more..

in order to define new cloud code function you will need to use the following code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("{YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME}", function (request, response) {
     // write your code, require some npm module and more...
});
```

In order to create server side hook you can write the following code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("{PARSE_OBJECT_NAME}", function (request, response) {
    // write your code and handle before saving an object
});
```

Triggering cloud code functions can be done easily via parse-server REST API or via parse-server client SDK's (iOS,Android,JavaScript and more)

There is a great guide on cloud code in here:

http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/cloudcode/guide/

Good Luck :)

Comment: This worked for me. For now, I am using local server but I want to deploy it on Google Cloud or Amazon cloud. If you're aware of this process, can you provide some link pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Your cloud code should be deployed together with the parse-server. Inside your parse-server there is a cloud folder and inside there you have main.js